# Understanding the Riemann-Integrability of $ 2 \pi$-periodic functions on $( 0,2\pi )$ whose absolute value squared is Riemann-integrable

Tags: integration, analysis, riemann-integration

In my lecture, we are considering the vector space
$$\{ f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \, | \,  f(x+2\pi) = f(x) \, \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } \| f \| < \infty \}$$
where
$$\| f \| := \int_0^{2\pi} |f(t)|^2 dt$$

If we assume that $\| f \| < \infty$, then this means that $|f(t)|^2$ is Riemann-integrable. I asked myself whether I could say something about the Riemann integrability of $|f(t)|$ or even $f(t)$.

I know that the absolute value of a Riemann-integrable function is also Riemann-integrable. Furthermore, the square of a Riemann-integrable function is Riemann-integrable too. However, I am not sure whether the respective reverse statements are true or not.

Does anyone know something about it?

Comment: Do you know any examples of bounded functions on bounded intervals which are not Riemann integrable?

Comment: I know that the Dirichlet function $D$ is not Riemann integrable. So if I consider $g=D-1/2$, then $|g| = 1/2$. So $|g|$ is Riemann integrable while $g$ is not. Is that argument correct?